# Error retrieving access token: TypeError: Cannot read property 'project_id' of undefined

Tags: clasp

I am new to clasp.

After the initial login via: 
clasp login
I am able to login to script.google.com
Next, I have created a project and pushed the file via:
clasp push

Now, I have logged out using:
clasp logout

Help required here: Now, if I am trying:

clasp login --creds ./.clasp.json

I am getting, "Error retrieving access token: TypeError: Cannot read property 'project_id' of undefined".

Please guide me on how to login via --creds?

Answer (score 7):

TLDR: You're using the config file (`.clasp.json`), and not a credentials file (`creds.json` or other) from the Google Cloud Project console.

---

When you log in, the default storage of credentials is in a file named **`.clasprc.json`** in the `~` directory (`C:\Users\<user>\` on Windows):

```
$ clasp login
Logging in globally...
 Authorize clasp by visiting this url:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&.....

Authorization successful.

Default credentials saved to ~\.clasprc.json (C:\Users\<user>\.clasprc.json).
```

Note that this file (**`.clasprc.json`**) is not the same as **`.clasp.json`**.

#### [clasprc.json](https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/2.0.1/src/auth.ts#L19-L43) format:

The contents of this file purportedly depend on the auth type, global or local:

```
// GLOBAL: clasp login will store this (~/.clasprc.json):
 {
   "access_token": "XXX",
   "refresh_token": "1/k4rt_hgxbeGdaRag2TSVgnXgUrWcXwerPpvlzGG1peHVfzI58EZH0P25c7ykiRYd",
   "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script ...",
   "token_type": "Bearer",
   "expiry_date": 1539130731398
 }
```

Local auth stores the client secret / etc, and is generally required if you plan to use [`clasp run`](https://github.com/google/clasp/tree/2.0.1#run) to execute a function via the Google Apps Script API.

```
// LOCAL: clasp login will store this (./.clasprc.json):
 {
   "token": {
     // as above
   },
   // Settings
   "oauth2ClientSettings": {
     "clientId": "807925367021-infvb16rd7lasqi22q2npeahkeodfrq5.apps.googleusercontent.com",
     "clientSecret": "9dbdeOCRHUyriewCoDrLHtPg",
     "redirectUri": "http://localhost"
   },
   "isLocalCreds": true
}
```

(In practice, both files will have the format of the `LOCAL` file--properties `token`, `oauth2ClientSettings`, and `isLocalCreds`--though the value of `isLocalCreds` will be false for a global login.)

#### [clasp.json](https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/2.0.1/README.md#project-settings-file-claspjson) format:

```
{
  "scriptId": "",
  "rootDir": "build/",
  "projectId": "project-id-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "fileExtension": "ts",
  "filePushOrder": ["file1.ts", "file2.ts"]
}
```

Note that `clasp.json` is *configuration of the script files* and `clasprc.json` is **stored** *credential / authorization of the user*. **Neither** of them is the appropriate credential file for logging in locally.

### Resolving the error

The specific error you get is a result of you providing the incorrect file. Your supplied "credential" file does not have the required properties, and thus when clasp attempts to [read from that property](https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/b5701c70be348fd9d2e2b4eb85e670c3298d9e6e/src/auth.ts#L92)

```
  console.log(LOG.CREDS_FROM_PROJECT(options.creds.installed.project_id));
```

you get the error:

> Error retrieving access token: TypeError: Cannot read property 'project_id' of undefined

You can obtain the proper credentials file from your Apps Script project's Google Cloud Project page, i.e. `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?authuser=0&project=<some project id>`

This file will have the format:

```
{
    "installed":{
        "client_id":"<stuff>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "project_id":"<some project id>",
        "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret":"<more stuff>",
        "redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]
    }
}
```

If your credentials file does not have that format, you cannot use it to log in locally.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying in detail. Will definitely try it and revert.

Comment: I tried your way and got a good understanding of how clasp login works. I found that when we enter the command: clasp login, it saves .clasprc in user profile. And, moment we run clasp logout, this file gets deleted. My requirement is there is a way to login using clasp next time without going to UI again or using "creds" option?

Comment: @nishant I believe `clasp login` will always result in an OAuth consent screen because you must authorize **clasp itself** too, not just your Apps Script application. If you just need to "change user" then you will need to write your own tooling to manipulate the location / name of the .clasprc file.

Comment: I followed the steps to generate a proper credentials file as explained by you. `{"web":{"client_id":"123456789-7fpnk0jhfvhe63h8s4jt1lgehj948s4o.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"ABCD","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"kcKK1aLan8TlDs0zXXssdsd","redirect_uris":["https://localhost/authorize"]}}`. However, error is still the same: Error retrieving access token: TypeError: Cannot read property 'project_id' of undefined.

Comment: Well, I am able to generate a correct creds file from GCP. However, now it is giving "Could not read API credentials. Are you logged in globally?" while doing: clasp login --creds creds-file. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

I also had this error, when I incorrectly chose "Web Application" for oauth type, instead of "Desktop Application", in this case main section is "web", instead of "installed", and I receive same

```
Error retrieving access token: TypeError: Cannot read property 'project_id' of undefined
```

Wrong oauth client looked like

```
{
    "web": {
        "client_id": "<STUFF>",
        "project_id": "<STUFF>",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret": "<STUFF>"
    }
}
```

while correct one was

```
{
    "installed": {
        "client_id": "<STUFF>",
        "project_id": "<STUFF>",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret": "<STUFF>",
        "redirect_uris": [
            "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
            "http://localhost"
        ]
    }
}
```

The script tries to resolve "**installed.project_id**" variable and fails.