# CLASP Local Login

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a local login file for my google scripts project in order to set it up so it'll work in an automated deploy process.

As far as I can tell, `clasp login` will create a file in your home directory which authenticates you with scripts.google.com, but that file isn't applicable to to local logins because it's missing some properties like "project_id".

When looking for how to create a file to run with `clasp login --creds {file}` there doesn't seem to be a straight forward way to generate one of those files in your local directory, which is how I would like to set up my deployment pipeline.

Most of the documentation on the internet says that you can create your own file by navigating to your GCP project and exporting a service account json file, but I don't know how to tell which GCP  project my google script project is associated with.

I'm super lost, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Hello @AlexanderBrehm, what do you mean by `"Here doesn't seem to be a straight forward way to generate one of those files in your local directory"`, why isn't the file in which the credentials are stored of use to you? Cheers!

Comment: I think you're referring to the file that's generated in the home directory when you run ```clasp login``` 
Unfortunately, that file is missing some information that ```clasp login --creds {file}``` requires

-------------------------------------------
    my-computer src (master) $ clasp login --creds ./.clasprc.json
    Warning: You seem to already be logged in *locally*. You have a ./.clasprc.json
    Logging in locally...

    Error retrieving access token: TypeError: Cannot read property 'project_id' of undefined
-------------------------------------------

Comment: I updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: Hello @AlexanderBrehm, I understand now. You might want to take a look into this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54533397/error-retrieving-access-token-typeerror-cannot-read-property-project-id-of-u). Is this of any help to you? Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the response, I appreciate your time. Unfortunately, I've already read that question and I'm stuck on the part of the solution where they say "You can obtain the proper credentials file from your Apps Script project's Google Cloud Project page, i.e. https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?authuser=0&project=<some project id>" I haven't been able to make it past that point because I have no clue what my project id is or where to find it.

Comment: Hello @AlexanderBrehm, if you want to retrieve the `project id` and the `credentials`, you will have to go to the Apps Script script and check the `Resources` -> `Cloud Platform Project...` OR if you don't have a script in Apps Script you should create a GCP project for which you can later attach the local script and use the credentials. Is this what you were looking for? Cheers!

Comment: Alright, that helped. With that revelation and the link from before I think I got a handle on how to generate a local credentials file. Unfortunately I think I'm still stuck because even if I'm logged in locally, I still get the "are you logged in globally? prompt" when attempting to run ```clasp deploy``` which leads me to believe that clasp deploy does not support the local as opposed to global logins. Would you happen to know if I'm right?

Comment: Hello @AlexanderBrehm, I think I am misunderstanding your last comments. Which file exactly are you trying to use for the login? Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, I changed topics. I think we're good for now, you helped me with my question, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to log in locally I performed these steps:

In your project, make sure it's associated with a project id
(in the legacy editor > resources > cloud platform project > set your project id)

Then go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?authuser=0&project=your-project-id, create an Oauth2.0 clientid, and download your client secret and save it locally

From there you can locally log in by running `clasp login -creds /path/to/file`

Thanks to ALE13 and [Error retrieving access token: TypeError: Cannot read property 'project_id' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54533397/error-retrieving-access-token-typeerror-cannot-read-property-project-id-of-u)